# How do I find all the rows that share column value 2 based on column value 1?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
Movie          Actor      Year 
Ocean's Eleven Brad Pitt  2001
Ocean's Eleven George Clooney 2001
Ocean's Eleven Matt Damon 2001
Pulp Fiction   Samuel L. Jackson 1994
Pulp Fiction   John Travolta 1994
```

etcc...

It basically is a long list of movies with the main actors in that movie
Now my question: how can I find all the movies that share atleast one actor?

For example:

- Ocean's Eleven and Ocean's Twelve both share Brad Pitt and George Clooney
- Ocean's Eleven and Fury they both have Brad Pitt
- Ocean's Eleven and Pulp Fiction do not share any main actors so it should not be found

I know I can use the intersect function to find overlapping elements in vectors/lists however I'm not sure how to do this for all unique movies in my dataframe! I thought of writing a for loop but I figured that there is probably an easier method.

Comment: Could you please include a representative sample dataset using `dput(movie_data)` that includes at least the films mentioned in your expected outcome paragraph. This will make it easier to find and test solutions.

Answer (score 0):

`split` `Movie` by `Actor` then subset for lengths > 1.

```
split(dat$Movie, dat$Actor) |> {\(.) .[lengths(.) > 1]}()
# $`Brad Pitt`
# [1] "Ocean's Eleven" "Fury"
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(Movie = c("Ocean's Eleven", "Ocean's Eleven", 
"Ocean's Eleven", "Fury", "Fury", "Pulp Fiction", "Pulp Fiction"
), Actor = c("Brad Pitt", "George Clooney", "Matt Damon", "Brad Pitt", 
"Someone Else", "Samuel L. Jackson", "John Travolta"), Year = c(2001L, 
2001L, 2001L, 2222L, 2222L, 1994L, 1994L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

We may use `n_distinct` after grouping in `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
 group_by(Actor) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(Movie) > 1) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  Movie          Actor      Year
  <chr>          <chr>     <int>
1 Ocean's Eleven Brad Pitt  2001
2 Fury           Brad Pitt  2222
```